upsert all Profile's tab settings (without using md api)
I know we can use PermissionSetTabSetting to retrieve parentId and visibility. Documentation says that it's possible to retrieve, upsert at least. Is it possible to manage Profile tab settings the same way? Does some separated object exist? Or we need to try md api

ProfileTabSetting is a metadata type, so you have to use the Metadata API.  See the documentation.
